# nginx execute .php as .gif file rewrite rules

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

its been quite a challenge for me to do access this:

```
mysite.com/cookie/image.php?perma=perma1
```

as this;

```
mysite.com/cookie/perma1.gif
```

or

```
mysite.com/cookie/image.php?perma=perma1
```

as

```
mysite.com/cookie/perma2.gif
```

So whenever I request `perma1.gif or perma2.gif` in background nginx would run

```
image.php?perma=perma1
```

and

```
image.php?perma=perma2
```

respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for your problem the right rule for your nginx server.conf should be:

```
location ~* ^/cookie/(.*)\.(gif)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cookie/image.php?perma=$1;
}
```

This rule means:

1. Only be used in the subfolder /cookie/
2. Only be used by gif Filetype
3. trying if an gif exists
4. if not redirect to cookie/image.php
5. and give the gif filename as GET perma

... this should work for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> So *whenever* I request perma1.gif or perma2.gif in background nginx would run

This means that `try_files` is completely unnecessary, Not only the answer by @MatWer would always attempt to check the existence of e.g. `/cookie/perma1.gif`, but also check for existence of directory `/cookie/perma1.gif/` (that is two unnecessary system `stat` calls).

Most efficient is a simple rewrite placed in `server` context (outside any `location`):

```
rewrite ^/cookie/(.*)\.gif$ /cookie/image.php?perma=$1 last;
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems like e neat-er solution.

Comment: Thats right, it checks also the exist of the directory! But in my use cases it is often important to check it back if there is maybe a ressource or not befor passing the input to php. So with the solution of try_files you don't want to stuck in error analyses on rewrite problems.